# What is mean Basic Token on Header params?

Tags: api, post

[image]

What do I go through in the Authorization field?

Im using the Postman for the tests

The document that i reading -> https://developers.ipag.com.br/en-us/payment?id=create-payment

Comment: That link is broken. Also, if you have any question about the documentation, it would be better to ask those for clarification who wrote it

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer!
Basically we have to go to the Authorization tab in the Postman and set the type with Basic Auth and after set up your credentials of the your respective application!